# How do I get a column to trickle down from a Calendar into all of the "seperate" views of that calendar?

Tags: site-column

How do I get a column to trickle down from a Calendar into all of the "seperate" views of that calendar?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's possible to add a column to many views directly, using out of the box features.

You would have to perform some custom development using Visual Studio, or use PowerShell.

Have a look at this post on MSDN from someone who wants to do a similar task:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/79cffa74-e6b5-4fd5-89a0-cc667d052f37